# Error: Two few arguments in function call

Tags: c++

I'm working on a program that measures how many second a merge sort will take to sort random elements which I based from the codes in here:

https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/time-comparison-of-quick-sort-insertion-sort-and-bubble-sort/

http://rextester.com/discussion/MKKVY46370/MergeSort

I'm getting an error from that says mergesort(0, length-1); has "two few arguments in call".

```
        #include <iostream.h>
        #include <fstream.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <time.h>

        void mergesort(int list[],int i,int j); void merge(int list[],int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2);


        long length = 1000; const long max_length = 3000;

        int list[max_length];


        void read() {
            ifstream fin("rand.dat", ios::binary);
            for (long i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {   fin.read((char*)&list[i], sizeof(int));
            }
            fin.close(); }

        void mergesort(int list[],int i,int j) {
            int mid;

            if(i<j)
            {
                mid=(i+j)/2;
                mergesort(list,i,mid);        //left recursion
                mergesort(list,mid+1,j);    //right recursion
                merge(list,i,mid,mid+1,j);    //merging of two 

        sorted sub-arrays
            } }   void merge(int list[],int i1,int j1,int i2,int j2) {
            int temp[1000];    //array used for merging
            int i,j,k;
            i=i1;    //beginning of the first list
            j=i2;    //beginning of the second list
            k=0;

            while(i<=j1 && j<=j2)    //while elements in both lists
            {
                if(list[i]<list[j])
                    temp[k++]=list[i++];
                else
                    temp[k++]=list[j++];
            }

            while(i<=j1)    //copy remaining elements of the first 

        list
                temp[k++]=list[i++];

            while(j<=j2)    //copy remaining elements of the second 

        list
                temp[k++]=list[j++];

            //Transfer elements from temp[] back to a[]
            for(i=i1,j=0;i<=j2;i++,j++)
                list[i]=temp[j]; }   int main() {



        double t1, t2;



        read();
                t1 = clock();
                mergesort(0, length - 1);
                t2 = clock();
                cout << "Merge Sort\t: " << (t2 - t1)/CLK_TCK << " 

        sec\n";


            switch (length)     {   case 100 :
                length = 500;
                break;  case 500 :
                length = 1000;
                break;  case 1000 :
                length = 1500;
                break;  case 1500 :
                length = 2000;
                break;  case 2000 :
                length = 2500;
                break;  case 2500 :
                length = 3000;
                break;  case 3000 :
                length = 3001;
                break;  }

            }
            return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In what line does the compiler report the error? Can you create a minimal working example?

Comment: @Svaberg The error came from this: read();
                t1 = clock();
                mergesort(0, length - 1);
                t2 = clock();
                cout << "Merge Sort\t: " << (t2 - t1)/CLK_TCK << " 

        sec\n";

Answer (score 1):

`mergesort` takes 3 arguments; you are only passing 2.  The first argument is supposed to be an array.

Comment: I've added an array as the first argument but now I got an error that says "Expression syntax"

Comment: can u show the new call of mergesort() after adding array

Comment: should just be mergesort(list, 0, length-1); since the outer array is also called list

Comment: @JasonLang it worked. there is no error now. but the program isnt compiling. T_T